# Getting SQL (filled with prompts inputs) from .rep report

Tags: sql, business-objects

I'm using Business Objects Desktop Intelligence program (.rep files), I know how to get query in SQL form form .rep file, this SQL code contains certain lines like this one : `@Prompt('Select data','D',,mono,free)`, in time of execution it will be filled with data provided by user of .rep file (certain date in some format in example above), is it possible to get SQL code of query with filled `@Prompt` places  after execution of report - after user chose needed parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the actual SQL statements, your best bet would be to trace the statements on the **server side** (i.e. the database). If your reports are based on a universe, there are ways to add comments to the generated SQL statements to identify them more easily. See [Identifying SAP BusinessObjects queries using END_SQL](http://www.dallasmarks.org/blog/2011/10/tips-and-tricks-identifying-business-objects-queries-using-end_sql/) for more information and examples of this technique.

Depending on the database you're using, you could also capture this information on **client side** using a utility like [SQL Monitor](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/558.aspx).

> SQL Monitor is a utility that monitors Oracle, MySQL, and DB2 Client DLL calls, allowing you to capture all SQL calls a program sends to the database via the client DLLs

Comment: Is there similar tool to SQL Monitor for which could track SQL Server calls ?

Comment: Have a look at this post: [SQL Client Profiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256806/sql-client-profiler). AFAIK, your options (on client side) are to use ODBC tracing or Wireshark network sniffing.