# Can we see SQL Server table data using wireshark?

Tags: sql-server, wireshark

Suppose, I fire a query from SQL client to SQL Server:

```
select * from user
```

I believe, the SQL Server Profiler does not show the actual table data (rows). Can rows be viewed using wireshark software?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562682/how-do-i-filter-sql-server-traffic-between-app-and-db-servers-using-wireshark) mentions about using filters to capture SQL traffic, but does it capture table data?

This [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2436/what-does-my-sql-server-data-look-like-over-the-wire/) talks about capturing the SQL query fired using wireshark, but does not talk about capturing resultset.

Comment: Did you try it? I believe it understands the TDS protocol but haven't tried myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decode SQL Server traffic with wireshark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023589/how-can-i-decode-sql-server-traffic-with-wireshark)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Most likely it's already supported by SQL Server. SQL Server's Extended Events are probably a lot easier to use than trying to decode TDS. SQL Server profiler is considered deprecated with no new functionality added since 2012. Extended Events are faster and far more detailed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: as far as I know there is no way to capture result sets with extended events. Do tell if you have information to the contrary.

Comment: @NickKavadias The link you mentioned talks about capturing SQL query and not the resultset, so my question is not duplicate.

Comment: The result set is streamed as TDS as well and shows up in the capture just like the request. There's no conceptual difference.